# How to Monitor Aborted Connections on Port 80 With tcpdump

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unix, tcpdump

Can I use tcpdump to detect Aborted connections on port 80 (Apache) originating from a specific IP (my remote IP). I can reproduce the Aborted connection in my web browser, but I have no way to verify if the request is getting to my server. I tried this, but couldn't really tell if a connection was Aborted.

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0 -s 0 src or dst port 80|grep -F "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that an "Aborted" connection happens when a TCP packet is sent the tells the connection to reset, the flag that represents this is the `RST` flag.

You can filter for RST using `tcpdump -i eth1 'tcp[13] & 4 = 4'`. Also, a bit off point but grepping tcp dump is a little lazy, you can always add `dst host X or src host X` to your filter.